# Ubuntu Install wont recognize partitions

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I am a Linux noob, so try not to yell at me,

I am attempting to install Unbuntu through a USB, however when i go to install, the driver doesn't recognize the partition i made to install on my hard drive, the only thing it recognizes is the free space in my USB in /dev/sda directory. I've turned off fast start up, and disabled secure boot, the partition I made IS basic, NOT dynamic space. However still nothing. Please help :(

Also, following this [link](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), for step 6, the "Something Else" option is not available for me.

Comment: Is your drive set to AHCI in BIOS?  Before you go changing it if it isn't, you might want to check with Windows sites / support to make sure that switching over to AHCI is safe.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, for your first time experience, I suggest to find another PC not in use and do it without hesitations. Or your Windows OS doesn't have any important files to you, everyone breaks more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you backed up your disk before messing with it.  I use "Redo" to get an image of the disk before I tweak things.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/redobackup/

It wasn't clear from your post whether Ubuntu is seeing the disk onto which you wish to install Ubuntu.  Is it seeing that disk at all, or just not seeing the partition?

If it is not seeing that disk at all, try rebooting from the Ubuntu USB disk and then running GParted to look at and/or edit the partitions you created.  Make the partition where you want it to install Linux an "ext4" partition.  Make sure it also has a partition with "linux-swap" as the file system.  Usually, these are made for you by the installation process, but if it isn't seeing the disk, it might be necessary for you to create them and then install to them.  But be sure you are backed up before you do this.

I'm sure there are gurus here who know better than I do, so I defer to them.